# Spring security redirecting to login page for authenticated urls

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring. I  am creating a spring mvc app. I have a admin url "/admin/".If I login with user credentials with ROLE_ADMIN then I can access the admin page. Right now this scenario is working fine. But If I have not logged in with ROLE_ADMIN and I try to access /admin/ url spring security is redirecting me to /login page.

Here what I want to not expose to outer world that /admin/(or admin url exists) url need authentication. And I want to show default exception page or home page if someone who is not authorized try to access /admin/ url.

Also I need to have custom "/login" url like "/custom_url/" instead of "/login"

But right now I don't have any idea how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

### applicationContext.xml

```
</bean>  
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" 
access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

     <security:form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/admin"
        always-use-default-target="true"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
   <security:logout logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="true" logout-
url="/logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                    authorities-by-username-query="SELECT 
username, authority From authorities WHERE username = ?"
                                    users-by-username-query="SELECT 
username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

### Login Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestParam(value="error", required = false) String 
error, @RequestParam(value="logout",
        required = false) String logout, Model model) {
    if (error!=null) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid username and password");
    }

    if(logout!=null) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "You have been logged out successfully.");
    }

    return "login";
}
```

### login.jsp

```
   <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

   <form name="loginForm" action="<c:url 
value="/j_spring_security_check" />" method="post">
            <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                <div class="error" style="color: #ff0000;">${error}</div>
            </c:if>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">User: </label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" 
class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" 
class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" 
value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
```

I am using Spring security 4.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `authentication-failure-url="/login?error"` to `authentication-failure-url="/"`. This will redirect you to Home page.

The correct xml-snippet in `applicationContext.xml` is as following:

```
 <security:form-login
    login-page="/login"
    default-target-url="/admin"
    always-use-default-target="true"
    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
    authentication-failure-url="/"
    username-parameter="username"
    password-parameter="password" />
```

**Note:** You can change value of `authentication-failure-url` attribute to an exception page as per need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I tried by changing  authentication-failure-url but it has no effect on current scenario rather on invalid credentials it is redirecting to home page.